# Get the template I'm currently editing

Tags: templates, database

I'm developing a custom form field for my template and I need to know the name of this template from inside this form field. While otherwise I would do a `setQuery` to look for `client_id=0 and home="1"`, this case is different because you can edit template styles even if they're not set as default.

My guess is that I need to read the current URL, get the item id and do a `setQuery` on this one. For that I would probably have to do some Uri method I'm still looking for.

Any idea if there's a better way please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it from `template` field in the form.

```
if ($this->form)
{
    $template = $this->form->getValue('template');
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Even more handy and probably more appropriate. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yea, like I've explained above this worked for me:

```
$id = Uri::getInstance()->getVar('id');
$query = Factory::getDbo()->setQuery("SELECT `template`, `params` FROM `#__template_styles` where `id` = '" . $id . "'");
$templateObject = $query->loadObject();

// usage
// get template name
$template = $templateObject->template;

// get template params
$templateParams = $templateObject->params;
```

But yet again, if you guys have a better idea, make sure to let it out.
Cheers!