# Get template params from the input

Tags: templates, jinput

Previously I was looking into how to get [the template](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28874/get-the-template-im-currently-editing) I'm currently editing, now I need to make use of a `templates/templateName/helper.php` file which would need a different kind of request.

```
// this gets me the template
$app = Factory::getApplication('site');
$template = $app->input->getValue('template');
```

**Question:**

How can I get the params from the input for the known `$template`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the parameters of a **specific** template inside the Helper, you could write a small database query, like so:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\Registry\Registry;

class TplCassiopeiaHelper
{
    private $params = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->params = $this->getParams();

        // You can now access specific parameters, inside the class, for example:
        // $this->params->get('colorName')
    }

    protected function getParams()
    {
        $db = Factory::getDbo();

        $db->setQuery(
            $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select('params')
                ->from('#__template_styles')
                ->where('template = ' . $db->q('cassiopeia'))
                ->where('client_id = 0')
        );
        $registry = new Registry;
        $registry->loadString($db->loadResult());

        return $registry;
    }
}
```

Or, when you instantiate the helper class, you could pass `$this->params` as a constructor argument.

Comment: Say I instantiate a new `TplCassiopeiaHelper` inside its `doSomeAjax` method, where/what would be the source of `$this->params` in that case?

Comment: You don't need to instantiate the class inside its own ajax method. Instantiate the class once and pass in the template parameters via the constructor if you want

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this example:

```
$this->params->get('sitedescription'))
```

In this instance my XML looks like this:

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="advanced">
            <field name="sitedescription"
                   type="text"
                   default=""
                   label="JGLOBAL_DESCRIPTION"
                   description="JGLOBAL_SUBHEADING_DESC"
                   filter="string"/>
            <field name="framework" type="list" default="bootstrap4" required="true" label="TPL_STARTER_BOOTSTRAP_4_LABEL" description="TPL_STARTER_BOOTSTRAP_4_DESCRIPTION">
                <option value="">TPL_STARTER_BOOTSTRAP_4_DEFAULT_OPTION</option>
                <option value="bootstrap4">Bootstrap4</option>
                <option value="foundation6">Foundation 6</option>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```